# Why ChronoLocalDate and ChronoLocalDateTime are designed as completely different interfaces?

Tags: java, localdate

I tried to create a generic method that serialises either LocalDateTime or LocalDate and bumped into a problem. I cannot just take them and use as a template parameter like  or similar as they implement different interfaces ChronoLocalDateTime and ChronoLocalDate correspondingly. Both of these interfaces are very similar and moreover format method is exactly the same in both cases.
I am just curious if it was done intentionally or it is just a design flaw?

Comment: It seems that they decided to use composition instead of inheritance, but I do not really understand why don't these interfaces have some generic parent. What drawbacks this approach would have?

Comment: While I am no mind-reader and cannot answer your question: What good would a common interface between exactly these two classes (not comprising, say, `OffsetDateTime`) have? They are two different beasts after all. And if you think you may benefit from handling them uniformly in some context, see how far the `TemporalAccessor` interface may get you.

Comment: Your statement that there is no generic parent is not true. There is one: `java.time.temporal.Temporal` Nevertheless, I don't see any good use-case to unify both `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` and would rather put your design approach in question.

Comment: Temporal is a common parent, but it is useless in my case. The use-case is simple, I have many Date and DateTime serializers with similar logic that use different formatters. I want to create one generic serializer that implements mentioned logic and accepts different formatters.

Comment: No, use two serializers, one for `LocalDate` and one for `LocalDateTime`. Eventually, you can also deploy the composite pattern because a `LocalDateTime` contains a `LocalDate`. `ChronoLocalDate` is a bad interface, its javadoc reads like `don't use me' - for good reasons.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did. After all it's better to have two serializers instead of dozens. I was just curious why it was designed in this way?